# This method must return a result of type boolean - android options menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to add an `Activity` that will be launched on an `ActionBar` item click. However on the `onOptionsItemSelected` method I get `"This method must return a result of type boolean"`. This happens since I added case 2.

Why is this?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(viewIntent);
        break;
    case R.id.action_info:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Info.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);


        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because if it goes to `R.id.action_settings` case you aren't returning anything, but that method requieres a boolean being returned. True I would say since it could be handled. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(viewIntent);
        break;
```

you missed a return on the first case. You can replace the `break` with the `return` or add `return` at the end of the method

Answer (score 0):

```
case R.id.action_settings:
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(viewIntent);
    return true;//instead of break use this line
```

As the return type of `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` is boolean you must return a `boolean` value.Without returning a `boolean` if you break you will get that error `This method must return a result of type boolean`.However if you add a `return` at the end of the method instead, that will work fine too.